# Is there a way to set a modified SVG in runtime as custom icon in leafletjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet

I'm using leaflet js and want to set my customized icon for the marker with different angles. Is there a way to do so in runtime? 
Previously, I tried "react-Samy-SVG" but that didn't work because in the leaflet I should provide a file path for `iconUrl` property.

```
        var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: require('../../public/images/black-plane.svg'),
        iconRetinaUrl: require('../../public/images/black-plane.svg'),
        iconSize: [32, 32],
        iconAnchor: null,
        popupAnchor: null,
        shadowUrl: null,
        shadowSize: null,
        shadowAnchor: null,
        className: 'leaflet-custom-marker'
    });
```

Obviously, I don't want to generate SVGs for all my desired angles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Rotated Marker library. https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker
The Demo page has corrupted cdn links ... use this demo: https://erasta.github.io/Leaflet.RotatedMarker/example.html

```
L.marker([48.8631169, 2.3708919], {
    rotationAngle: 45
}).addTo(map);
```

or

```
marker.setRotationAngle(newAngle)
```

It works with SVG Icons

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me. Besides, I use leaflet js version 1.6.0.

Comment: Why it is not working? What error you get? I created a example (Leflet 1.6.0) for you: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/unmw2jqc/

Comment: Thank you so much for your example, it works (I've forgotten to add leaflet.rotatedMarker.js to my project0. Currently, I have two questions. First, the rotation does not work at all time and sometimes it's not working properly. Second, when I use marker after polylineDecorator function it doesn't show anything!

Comment: Can you create a example?

Comment: Yes. This link is my program, which is written by Preact and JavaScript: bit.ly/2rzhye2. This program can run with ReactJS too. Thanks.